# Python HTTPServer Exceptions cause it to fail

Tags: python, http, error-handling

I've tried many different ways of writing a simple HTTP server for Python (using IronPython in a hosted environment) and whenever there is an error (e.g. run-time error) the Python environment just hangs, rather than shutting down and reporting the error.

Update:

There is a [comment on an answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178536/in-python-how-to-get-a-udpserver-to-shutdown-itself/5182733#5182733) that suggest that calling "self.server.shutdown()" in a request handler also causes a Python web server to hang in Windows.

So possibly run-time exceptions lead to the same problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what kind of errors (and corresponding code) cause it to crash?

Comment: No crash, it just hangs. I'm not sure how to get any more diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do something along the lines of:

```
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except RuntimeError:
    httpd.shutdown()
    sys.exit()
```

btw, this is for python 3 and it assumes that you have the sys module imported.